# php function call after javascript validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

Hello i have a form in html and I want to validate its input fields by javascript and if all are true then call a php function that add the form input fields to a database. On the form I added the `onsubmit` tag  at the form but the php function is called either way. Here is what I've done so far:

signup.php

```
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="student_signup.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td> Όνομα:</td> 
                                <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" onblur="validateName('name')"> </td>
                                <td><span id="nameError" style="display: none;"></span> <td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> Επώνυμο:</td> 
                                <td><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" onblur="validateName('surname')"> </td>
                                <td><span id="surnameError" style="display: none;"></span> <td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> Username:</td> 
                                <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" onblur="validateName('username')"> </td>
                                <td><span id="usernameError" style="display: none;"></span> <td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> Κωδικός:</td> 
                                <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" onblur="validatePassword('password')" > </td>
                                <td><span id="passwordError" style="display: none;"></span> <td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> Επαλήθευση κωδικού:</td> 
                                <td><input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" onblur="validateConfirmPassword('password','passwordConfirm')"> </td>
                                <td><span id="passwordConfirmError" style="display: none;"></span> <td>
                            </tr>

        </form>
        </table>
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 .
    </body>

<php?

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
      echo "adding to database";
    foo();

} 

php>
```

validate.js

```
function validateForm() {

    var error = 0;

    if (!validateName('name')) {
        document.getElementById('nameError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
    }


    if (!validateEmail('password')) {
        document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
    }
alert(error);

    if (error > 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Currently everytime the message on the if statement is print although the alertbox prints "2". Is there anything so I can check the return of the javascript function and call the php function accordingly? 
Or I have to the validation on server side? Each time I a user inputs something a function is triggered and a message containing the error is printed next to the input field. If I do the validation at server-side this would be uselless. Is it a good approach to do the validation at both client and server side?
thx in advance!

Comment: I'm reading your question and unfortunately I'm not being able to get the point :) So, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687208/php-form-submits-before-javascript-validation/24687243#24687243) and maybe it could be helpful. If not, try to clarify the last paragraph.

Comment: always do validation, server side, doing it client side is just a convince for your users.  It's very easy to get around javascript validation and I would not rely on it.  The way I like to do it is validate everything server side, and then use ajax to send the data for validation also sever side.  That way I don't have to code it 2 times and there is no difference between the two.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix currently on each item of input I have the onblur tag ,so the user is noted if he doesn't input something right. By doing it in server side this would be useless. Should I do it to both client side and server side?

Comment: @hex494D49 I updated my question hope it helped

Comment: Client Side validation is good for aesthetics and to make a smoother user experience (like prevent form submission without all fields) but always have a backup server side validation process.

Comment: @sharf exaclty! So i should to them both?

Comment: If it always alerts value 2, it means that both, name and password field don't validate, or there's a bug on your validation function - try removing the password field from validation and check what the alert says. Furthermore, server-side validation has nothing to do with client-side validation - they are two separated things, but they can be linked, to just not code the same think twice. But yes, it's a good practice to have validation on server-side as well.

Comment: Yes you should. You could set the JS to say "This is not a valid email address" or "Please enter a username" but then make sure the server does the same checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems to have moved away from a code related question to a good practice question.

As was said, client-side validation cannot be trusted. User can easily manipulate JS to bypass your validation and send erroneous information. That is why server-side validation is important. You can check the user input for errors/malicious scripts and clean/reject the data then. **Never trust user information to be correct/safe**

Client-side validation has its place though. It should be used to make the user experience better. Use it to check if a form is full filled out before submitting it, and if it's not highlight the missing fields and display a message. Client-side/JS should only be used to enhance the user experience, never rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
<body>
    <script>
        var error = 0;
        function validateForm() {
            alert(error);
            if (error > 0) {
                return false;
            } else{
                return true;
            }
        }
        function validateName(value,fieldName){
            if(!value){
                error++;
                if(fieldName === 'name'){
                    document.getElementById('nameError').style.display = "block";
                } else if(fieldName === 'surname'){
                    document.getElementById('surnameError').style.display = "block"; 
                } else if(fieldName === 'username'){
                    document.getElementById('usernameError').style.display = "block"; 
                }else if(fieldName === 'password'){
                    document.getElementById('passwordError').style.display = "block"; 
                }
            } else{
                if(error>0){
                    error--;
                }
                  if(fieldName === 'name'){
                    document.getElementById('nameError').style.display = "none";
                } else if(fieldName === 'surname'){
                    document.getElementById('surnameError').style.display = "none"; 
                } else if(fieldName === 'username'){
                    document.getElementById('usernameError').style.display = "none"; 
                }else if(fieldName === 'password'){
                    document.getElementById('passwordError').style.display = "none"; 
                }
            }
        }
        function validateConfirmPassword(value){
            if(value != document.getElementById('password').value){
                error ++;
                document.getElementById('passwordConfirmError').style.display = "block"; 
            }else{
                if(error>0){
                    error--;
                }
                 document.getElementById('passwordConfirmError').style.display = "none"; 
            }
        }
    </script>
    <form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> Όνομα:</td> 
                <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" onblur="validateName(this.value,'name')"> </td>
                <td><span id="nameError" style="display: none;">Name</span> <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Επώνυμο:</td> 
                <td><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" onblur="validateName(this.value,'surname')"> </td>
                <td><span id="surnameError" style="display: none;">Surname</span> <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Username:</td> 
                <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" onblur="validateName(this.value,'username')"> </td>
                <td><span id="usernameError" style="display: none;">username</span> <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Κωδικός:</td> 
                <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" onblur="validateName(this.value,'password')" > </td>
                <td><span id="passwordError" style="display: none;">Password</span> <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Επαλήθευση κωδικού:</td> 
                <td><input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" onblur="validateConfirmPassword(this.value)"> </td>
                <td><span id="passwordConfirmError" style="display: none;">confirm password</span> <td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>
</body>
```